# Why is this not selecting only records with a date older than 7 days?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to filter for rows that have a value of '1' in the active column and where the date in the lastfollowupemail_date column is 7 days or older from the current date.

Searching on the internet on many sites, this is the query I came up with, but for some reason it is not filtering correctly (the query is selecting records with a date less than 7 days from the current time).

Any ideas on why this may be occurring would be fantastic and much appreciated.  Thank you so much in advance!

```
SELECT * FROM e_sales_prospects
WHERE active='1' 
AND lastfollowupemail_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: My crystal ball broke.

Comment: more recent dates have higher values so you want to use `<` ;-)

Comment: @go-oleg  I tried switching that around, but it is still choosing even rows with the current date in that column.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @JaredFarrish  How do you go about achieving adding instead of subtracting like that?

Comment: Try `<` instead of `>`.

Answer (score 2):

if I'm reading this right you want rows that are older then seven days, in that case you want rows which have date *smaller* then so in my opinion it should be

```
lastfollowupemail_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: I'm sad to say that this did not work.  It is selecting even records with the same date in that column being filtered as the current date.  Any other ideas?

Comment: The code : `SELECT * FROM e_sales_prospects WHERE active='1' AND lastfollowupemail_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)` works perfectly well on test data, so without better insight into what you're doing, no more info can be provided